# Form validation for multiselect dropdown list in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

i have tried using various methods for setting form validation using codeigniter for a multiselect dropdown list,but is unable to set the rules properly. under here is the code i am using,kindly help. p.s. i have already tried implementing codes suggested on stackoverflow but in vain.

```
<select class="" name="travel_cat[]" multiple="multiple" id="travel_lst" data-placeholder="Select Travel Categories" style="width: 100%;">
                  <option value="adventure">Adventure</option>

                      <option value="arts&culture">Arts & Culture</option>

                      <option value="events">Events</option>

                      <option value="backpacking">Backpacking</option>

                      <option value="beach_holidays">Beach Holidays</option>

                    <option value="budget_travel">Budget Travel</option>

                    <option value="city_travels">City Travels</option>

                    <option value="day_trips">Day Trips</option>

                    <option value="honeymoons">Honeymoons</option>

                    <option value="family_trips">Family Trips</option>

                    <option value="weekend_gateway">Weekend Gateway</option>

                    <option value="history&architecture">History & Architecture</option>

                    <option value="luxury">Luxury</option>

                    <option value="nature">Nature</option>

                    <option value="road_trips">Road Trips</option>

                    <option value="wildlife">Wildlife</option>

                    <option value="religious">Religious</option>
                </select>  

$choice = $this->input->post("travel_cat");
    if(is_null($choice))
    {
        $choice = array();
    }
    $travel_cat = implode(',', $choice);
```

form validation:-

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('travel_cat', 'Travel Category', 'callback_check_default');

function check_default($array)
{
    foreach($array as $element)
    {
        if($element == '0')
        { 
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;        
}
```

Comment: No value `0` in your multi select box. It will always return you `true`

Comment: then what should i put instead of 0 ?

Comment: You need to check `if($element ==" ")
        { 
            return FALSE;
        }`

Comment: i even tried putting NULL instead of '0' still d same scenario.

Comment: what exactly do you want me to do,didnt get your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have replaced the callback function with the below mentioned code,and it worked fine.

```
function check_default()
{
    $choice = $this->input->post("travel_cat");
    if(is_null($choice))
    {
        $choice = array();
    }
    $travel_cat = implode(',', $choice);

    if($travel_cat != '')
        return true;
    else
        return false;   
}
```